# C# Number to BitMask32 to Values

Tags: c#, bitmask

I am getting a number such as 513. I need to convert this number to a bitmask32 then I need to count where each 1 bit is in the array

For Example
513 = 0 and 9

How would I go about converting the number to a bit32 then reading the values?

Right now I am just converting the number to a string binary value:

```
string bit = Convert.ToString(513, 2);
```

Would there be a more effective way to do this? How would I convert the value to a bit array?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var val = 513;
for(var pos=0;;pos++)
{
    var x = 1 << pos;
    if(x > val) break;
    if((val & x) == x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Get off. What a load of nonsense. It's a matter of coding style and completely insignificant. Perhaps I should have used hungarian notation too?

Comment: Gave it a +1.   It was helpful, just took me a little longer to read ancillary articles to see what type var would be int/uint by default.  New to C#, may have been a trivial question. :)

Comment: Ah. Sorry for my explosive response. Been using `var` for so long now, I'm completely acclimatised!

Answer (score 1):

The [BitVector32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx) class is an utility class that can help you out for this, if you really want to keep a bit map.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Collections;

int originalInt = 7;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(originalInt);
BitArray bits = new BitArray(bytes);
int ndx = 9; //or whatever ndx you actually care about

if (bits[ndx] == true)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Bit at index {0} is on!", ndx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To test bit #i in number `n`:

```
if ((n & (1 << i)) != 0)
```